# Getting a "No Content" response when posting a String

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

As I am new to WebAPI I have been experimenting with samples from the web.  I have an ApiController based class which handles Post, Get, etc.  From my client application, I can perform a Get and a Delete successfully but when I do a Post or a Put of a string, I can see the string value is null at the server and I get StatusCode 204, No Content at the client.  Using Postman I can successfully do a Post or Put so it seems to be a problem with my client app.

Have tried basing the client on .Net 4.7.2 as well as .NET Core 2.2

Here is the entire controller class of my WebAPI program:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        static List<string> strings = new List<string>()
        {
            "value0", "value1", "Value2"
        };

        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return strings;
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return strings[id];
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            strings.Add(value);
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
            strings[id] = value;
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            strings.RemoveAt(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code from my client Program:

```
    class Program
    {
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static void Main()
        {
            RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56037/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            try
            {
                var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/values/2", new StringContent("zzz"));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I set breakpoints in the Put and Post methods but the value of the string being passed is null, not the value I sent to the server.

Comment: Maybe check if you need to set some encoding format on the string content

Comment: You are using method `PutAdJsonAsync`, but you are not putting JSON. Try
`await client.PutAsync($"api/values/2", new StringContent("zzz"));`

Comment: I tried all variations of PutAsync and PutAsJsonAsync but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Id maybe try

```
var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/values/2", new StringContent("zzz"), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to enclose the string in quotes as follows:

```
var response = await client.PutAsync("api/values/0", "\"zzz\"", new StringTypeFormatter());
response = await client.PostAsync("api/values", "\"zzz\"", new StringTypeFormatter());
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want the item at the index, try:

```
   strings.ElementAt(id) = value;
```